# Why Remove last child does not work?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to remove the div old image and append a new one using last child(jQuery) but it does not work i get a new image appended beside the old one.
here is jQuery code

```
$(function() {

$('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e){
 var kleur=$(this).attr('class');
        switch(kleur){
            case 'color1':
             $("#div1 img:last-child").remove();
             alert($("#div1").html());
               $('#div1').append('<img src="color/color1.jpg">');
            break;
             case 'color2':
             $("#div1 img:last-child").remove();
               $('#div1').append('<img src="color/color2.jpg">');
             break;
            case 'color3':
             $("#div1 img:last-child").remove();
               $('#div1').append('<img src="color/color3.jpg">');
           break;
        }

        $('#hiddenimg').val(kleur);
    e.preventDefault(); 

 });
```

html code::

```
<?php
error_reporting('E_ALL');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$img=$_POST['img'];
$_SESSION['img']=$img;
?>
<div class="iconWrapper">
    <ul class="color">
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color1"></span></a>                               
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Selecteer "><span class="color2" ></span></a>                               
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color3"></span></a>                               
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color4"></span></a>                               
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form method="post" action="step3.php">    
    <div id="div1" >
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['img'])){
            echo '<img src="' . $_SESSION['img'] . '" >' ;
        } ?>
        <input name="color" type="text" value="" id="hiddenimg" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to close `div1`.

Comment: IMHO `img` tag is the one that needs closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try the jQuery :last selector: [link](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

for you need something like:

```
$("#div1 img:last").remove();
```

or a better version

```
$("#div1 img").filter(":last").remove();
```

I don't know to test right now, I hope this is your working solution :)

(Sorry for my english :"> )

Answer (score 0):

You need `:last` and not `:last-child`