# How to remove last appended input box

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue removing the last box i appended, here is how far i have gone, i'll appreciate any help i can get. Thanks.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
            var num = parseInt($('#num').val(), 10);
            if (!isNaN(num)) {
                  var $div = $('#div');
                for(var i=0;i< num;i++) {
                     $div.append('<input id="toremove" type="text" name="subject" class="form_element" placeholder="e.g Biology, Economics, Geography, Commerce, Agric.Sci" /> <a href"#" id="remove" class="delete"><a/>')   ;
                }
            }
        });

        $('#remove').on('click', function() {
            $('#toremove').lastChild().remove();
        });
```

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique. You can't have multiple elements having the same id.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830912/why-remove-last-child-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [:last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) here:

```
$('#remove').on('click', function () {
    $('#div input:text:last').remove();
});
```

Also, you can do this, since you're already using a class **form_element** for the input:

```
$('#remove').on('click', function () {
    $('#div .form_element:last').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use : (*don't use duplicate Id's .. use class instead*)

```
$('#toremove:last').remove();
```

You can change it to something like -

```
$div.append('<input class="toremove"...
```

and

```
$('#div .toremove:last').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. Got it working well with your explanation.